# How to call a df variable as the input for a t-test in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app and I want to include a simple one sample t-test for a continuous numeric variable in a dataframe. For my ui I have:

```
varSelectInput("Var1", label = "Variable?", data = df),
verbatimTextOutput("ttest")
```

and the server:

```
output$ttest <- renderPrint({
      
      t.test(x = input$Var1) 
      
  })
```

I get this error:

object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

I've seen an example of someone else doing something similar to this, and I can't tell the difference between their code and mine. I apologize because I know this must be a very noob question, but I'm still very new to shiny. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
output$ttest <- renderPrint({
      t.test(x = df[[input$Var1]])    
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't I'd start with the documentation for [varSelectInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/varSelectInput.html) specifically the Server value section specifically. it says "The input value should be used with rlang's rlang::!!(). For example, ggplot2::aes(!!input$variable)." so you may just be missing the !! from the input variable [here](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-force.html) is more specifics on the !! operator.

Comment: Hm I tried that as well, and got an error: invalid argument type